# package in java equals to what in C#?

Tags: c#, java

There is a package in JAVA named for example:

```
 package android.media.videoeditor;
```

and I know that there is something like that name in C#, so how do I get to that package in C#?

Comment: You should read about namespaces: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249357/difference-between-namespace-in-c-sharp-and-package-in-java

Comment: Other than having Android in the package name I do not think this has any relevance to Android.

Comment: @idish - Q: what did you wind up doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term you're looking for is [`namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I think he's asking the name of the particular namespace that is analogous to `android.media.videoeditor`

Comment: I doubt there is an exact equivalent.

Comment: So to get to that class I should do the following code? : using android.media.videoeditor?

Comment: @idish: No, there is no `android.media.videoeditor` namespace in .NET

Answer (score 3):

`using namespace_name`; in `c#`

`import package_name;` in `java`

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, "packages" in Java are analogous (but *not* identical!) to "namespaces" in C# and VB.Net.

As far as "video editor" in C#, look here:

- [C# Video editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022535/c-sharp-video-editor)
- [.Net sdk for video editing like Windows Movie Marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027753/net-sdk-for-video-editing-like-windows-movie-marker)